# Why saga effect not getting called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to add multiple action effect on my app. But I guess I am missing something. The effect function is not getting called. I am hoping is there something wrong with the naming? Ideally `yield all([` this should do the trick right?
Help me figure it out.

action.js

```
import {
  DEFAULT_ACTION,
  POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
  POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST_ERROR,
  POST_ADMIN_USER_DETAILS,
} from './constants';

import { setCookie } from '../../utils/helpers';

...... //rest of my actions

export function postAdminUserDetails(token) {
  console.log(token);
  // I see token in the console
  return {
    type: POST_ADMIN_USER_DETAILS,
    token,
  };
}
```

constants.js

```
export const POST_ADMIN_USER_DETAILS = 'app/AdminLogin/POST_ADMIN_USER_DETAILS';
```

saga.js

```
import { takeLatest, call, put, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import request from 'utils/request';

import { POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST, POST_ADMIN_USER_DETAILS } from './constants';

console.log(POST_ADMIN_USER_DETAILS)

import {
  postAdminLoginRequestSuccess,
  postAdminLoginRequestError,
} from './actions';

export function* triggerLogin({ params }) {
  const requestURL = new URL(`${API}/login`);

  ...... //rest of the logis, which is working
}

export function* triggerGetUser({ token }) {
  const requestURL = new URL(`${API}/profile`);

  console.log('callllled');
  // this is not even getting called :(
}

export default function* defaultSaga() {
  console.log('POST_ADMIN_USER_DETAILS')
  yield all([
    takeLatest(POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST, triggerLogin),
    takeLatest(POST_ADMIN_USER_DETAILS, triggerGetUser),
  ]);
}
```

reducer.js

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import {
  DEFAULT_ACTION,
  POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
  POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST_ERROR,
  POST_ADMIN_USER_DETAILS,
} from './constants';

export const initialState = fromJS({
  isLogin: false,
  hasError: false,
  loginResponse: null,
});

function adminLoginReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DEFAULT_ACTION:
      return state;
    case POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return state
        .set('isLogin', true)
        .set('hasError', false)
        .set('errorMessage', null)
        .set('loginResponse', null);
    case POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .set('isLogin', false)
        .set('hasError', false)
        .set('loginResponse', action.response);
    case POST_ADMIN_LOGIN_REQUEST_ERROR:
      return state
        .set('isLogin', false)
        .set('hasError', true)
        .set('errorMessage', action.errorMessage);
    case POST_ADMIN_USER_DETAILS:
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default adminLoginReducer;
```

Comment: Hi Subhendu, did you have connect the saga middleware with your Redux store ?

Comment: Please add your action dispatch statement as well. Are you dispatching that action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced the same issue, got it resolved by changing the path of the folder. So try the same or try to keep the saga file on the same folder level as your component file.